# why the object not following the curve?

Tags: mesh, properties

I want to animate this sphere. so I added a bezier curve and object constrain to sphere follow the path but soon after selecting the bezier curve. How can I make my sphere placed at the bezier curve to animate the path[image]

[image]g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve has start and end with no direct indices. Set current frame to zero, then select followed object and a curve as active, then `Set Parent To` > `Follow Path`, you will see a dotted line pointing to start of curve and move object to it. If Curve direction is wrong use `Edit Mode` > `Segments` > `Switch Direction`. Curve origin doesn't matter.

[image: Set Parent To > Follow Path]

By default animation adjusted to 100 frames starting from zero. You can tune Curve `Path Animation` in `Object Data` tab.

[image: Object Data > Path Animation]

Result in 60 frames.

[image: result]